# Why not working child page Jquery code in asp.net webform

Tags: c#

When I design a webform and coded in jquery for preview image from file upload without master page then its working properly. But when I add master page then Jquery not working.so how to prevent from this issue? my code is in follow

/*Master Page*/

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HomeMaster.master.cs" Inherits="CRMAPP.HomeMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <%--<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />--%>
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="../css/eLife-style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../css/sb-admin.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../css/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style>.side-bar { width:225px;background-color:#454243} .content { margin-left:225px;}.side-nav{height:3000px}</style>
   </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="main" >
    <div class="side-bar">
     <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top color" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../Admin/DashBoard.aspx">CRM Cable</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Top Menu Items -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-right top-nav">
               <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Test <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="../Admin/ChangePassword.aspx"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i> Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkLogout" Font-Underline="false" onclick="linkLogout_Click" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i>Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
                            <%--<a href="../LoginPage.aspx"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-power-off"></i> Log Out</a>--%>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Sidebar Menu Items - These collapse to the responsive navigation menu on small screens -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="../Admin/DashBoard.aspx" ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="stuff"  ><i class="fa fa-fw fa-bookmark-o"></i> Customer Stuff <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down right"></i></a>
                        <ul id="stuff" class="hide1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Admin/RegCust.aspx">Customer Registration</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Admin/CustomerSearch.aspx">Customer Search</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="complaints"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Complaints <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down right"></i></a>
                        <ul id="complaints" class="hide1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Admin/ComplaintReg.aspx">Complaint Registration</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Admin/ComplaintSearch.aspx">Complaint Search</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="javascript:;"  class="accounts"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list"></i> Accounts <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down right"></i></a>
                        <ul id="accounts" class="hide1">
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Admin/RecievePayment.aspx">Payment Receive </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="../Admin/PaymentSearch.aspx">Payment Search </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../Admin/CustomSMS.aspx"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o"></i> Custom SMS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li >
                        <a href="../Admin/UploadData.aspx"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-upload"></i> Upload Data</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="../Admin/help.aspx"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-question-circle"></i> Help</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
            <td><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder></td>    
        </tr>
    </table>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

/*Webform*/

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/HomeMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employe_Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="CRM_Employe.Employee.Employe_Register" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;
        function showimagepreview(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var filerdr = new FileReader();
                filerdr.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#EmpImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">



    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="empUpPanel" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
<table align="center" style="width: 60%;">
 <tr>
                <td class="style2">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="EmpfileUpload" runat="server" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" />
                    <%--<input type="file" name="filUpload" id="filUpload" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" />--%>
                <br />
                <asp:Image ID="EmpImage" runat="server" alt="uploaded image preview" />
                <%--<img id="imgprvw" alt="uploaded image preview"/>--%></td>
                <td class="style1">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;<br />
&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="CANCEL" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
    </ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```